# Joining tables and seeing Duplicate Records

Tags: sql-server-2012

I Use the query below to produce values from a table (BSCV1), based on results from another table (MshiftV1) using an inner Join on names and timestamps. I call the output "Correlation".

```
WITH Meanshift
AS
(
Select TOP 20 
  Timestamp
  ,Name
  ,Value
From  MshiftV1 
order by Value desc
)
select  
Timestamp 
,Name 
,Value
From BSCV1
inner join Meanshift 
ON (Meanshift.Name = LEFT(BSCV1.Value, 12) and   BSCV1.Timestamp = Meanshift.Timestamp )
```

I need to create another table called "Final_Meanshift" where I use the "Meanshift" subquery in the SQL code above but restrict it to only show values that also exist in the "Correlation" output.

I tried this:

```
WITH Meanshift
AS
(
Select TOP 20 
  Timestamp
  ,Name
  ,Value
From  MshiftV1 
order by Value desc
)
,Correlation
AS
(
select  
Timestamp 
,Name 
,Value
From BSCV1
inner join Meanshift 
ON (Meanshift.Name = LEFT(BSCV1.Value, 12) and   BSCV1.Timestamp = Meanshift.Timestamp )
)
Select TOP 20 
  Timestamp
  ,Name
  ,Value
From  MshiftV1 as MSHIFTV2 
Left Join Correlation on Correlation.Timestamp = MSHIFTV2.Timestamp AND Correlation.NAME = MSHIFTV2.NAME
```

This almost gets the job done, except that it produces duplicates of every record in "Final_Meanshift". NOTE: it is a "many-to-one" relationship (Many Correlation Matches to One Meanshift Match)

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Data would help so we can duplicate what you are doing.  Beyond that, you'll either need to add either SELECT DISTINCT or GROUP BY in your Final_Meanshift query.

Comment: If you have a "many to one" relationship you will likely end up with duplicates. Can you explain what Final_Meanshift should be doing?

Comment: Correlation will have names like Tag001A, Tag001A, Tag001F, Tag001C, TAG001A, Tag001C so you can see duplicates are normal here. However, Meanshift has records with names like Tag001A, Tag001B, Tag001C. Final_Meanshift should only show two records: Tag001A, and Tag001C and ignore Tag001B becuase it doesnt appear in Correlation. Also, it should not duplicate the Tag001A and Tag001C as many times it appears in Correlation.